# In $\mathbb{R}^3$, why do rotations about the $x_3$ axis not form a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

So given the matrix representation of a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$
$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$, why is it that the set of rotations about the $x_3$-axis (about different angles) doesn't form a vector subspace? Is it because multiplication by a scalar is not a rotation any more? Then it becomes a rotation plus scaling matrix?

Comment: This set isn't closed under scalar multiplication (as you note) nor is it closed under addition of matrices. It is closed under multiplication of matrices, and forms a group with that operation.

Comment: If you define the "addition" in this space by
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] \mathbin{\text{“}{+}\text{''}} \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} \cos\eta & -\sin\eta & 0 \\ \sin\eta & \cos\eta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$ $$ = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]  \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} \cos\eta & -\sin\eta & 0 \\ \sin\eta & \cos\eta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] = \cdots \cdots$$

Comment: $$ \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} \cos(\theta+\eta) & -\sin(\theta+\eta) & 0 \\ \sin(\theta+\eta) & \cos(\theta+\eta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$
then it's somewhat similar to a addition in a vector space, and scalar multiplication can be defined by ordinary multiplication of the argument $\theta$ by a real number.

Comment: @wobertson : Notice I said "somewhat similar". There will be differences, but right now I have to attend to other things.

Comment: Was just about to ask that @MichaelHardy, thanks and also Ethan for the confirmation!

Comment: Michael Hardy's idea is a lot like the way we can treat the real numbers as a vector space (with the usual addition and multiplication), except that the real numbers form equivalence classes (rotations by $\theta$ and by $\theta+2\pi$ are the same) so that the rotation by $\pi$ is its own additive inverse.